# swift update constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitextfield, constraints

I have a UIView in which there are 4 components, **UITextField**, a **UIActivityIndicator** and 2 **UIButtons**. All the components are using constraints set using storyboard.

Button1 UITextField UIActivityIndicator Button2

The **UITextField** displays the url of a **UIWebView** and the **UIActivityIndicator** corresponds to page loading.

When the page has loaded, **UIActivityIndicator** is hidden.

What I want is that when the loading is complete and **UIActivityIndicator** is hidden, the size of **UITextField** increases and use up the space used by the **UIActivityIndicator**.

Button1 UITextField Button2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

Rather than putting a constraint between the text field and the activity indicator, use a constraint between the text field and it's superview, with extra padding added to make room for the activity indicator.

Control-drag from the constraint into your view controller to create an outlet to it.

In your code, when you hide the activity indicator, reduce the constant setting on the constraint by the width of the activity indicator plus the space between the activity indicator and the text field so that the text field gets wider to fill the space that's freed by the hiding of the activity indicator.

If you want the text field to animate it's growth, put a call to `layoutIfNeeded()` in a call to `UIView.animate(duration:animations:)` immediately after the code that changes the constraint setting. That will cause the layout change to be animated.

Comment: Worked like a Charm!!

Comment: It takes a little while to think in terms of changing your layout by wiring up outlets to constraints, but that's a common way to work in Auto-Layout.